# jQuery Popup not working with output from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, modal-dialog

I'm looking to correct this script form popup each image with is corresponding texts. Actually it popup with all text in MySQL. Why isn't it showing the respective text for each image?

```
<?php
while ( $alaune = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $resultat6 ) ) {
    if ( ! empty( $alaune ) ) {
        echo '<div class="single_iteam"><img alt="" src="changements/une/images/' . $alaune["alaunePic"] . '" class="alaunePic">';
        echo '<div class="slider_article">';
        echo '<h2><a class="slider_tittle" href="#">' . $alaune["alauneTitre"] . '</a></h2>';
        echo '<p class="alaunetexte truncate">' . $alaune["alauneTexte"] . '</p>';

        ?>
        <a href="#" class="modal-trigger" data-modal="modal-name">Lire la suite...</a>
        <?php echo '</div>';

        echo '</div>';
    }
}

echo '</div><div class="modal" id="modal-name"><div class="modal-sandbox"></div><div class="modal-box"><div class="modal-header"><div class="close-modal">&#10006;</div>';

foreach ( $resultat6 as $alaune ) {
    echo '<h1>' . $alaune["alauneTitre"] . '</h1><p>' . $alaune["alauneTexte"] . '</p>';
}
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="modal-body"><br /><button class="close-modal"> Fermer </button></div></div></div>';

?>
```

Please have a look. Best regards.

Comment: Popup is working but result show all the texts not only once

Comment: They all have the same `modal-name`. You'll need to give them individual IDs. Aside from that, `if ( ! empty( $alaune ) ) {` is unnecessary since it won't enter the loop if it's falsey.

Comment: The answer is in your second loop :) That's how you display each article separately... In your second loop you are treating each item (article) individually as $alaune. In the first loop, you are printing the whole result (array). Il suffit de réécrire la première boucle en suivant la même syntaxe de la deuxième :)

Comment: @aynber, I guess he wants to output text from db records in same modal

Comment: We've got confusing views about the expected result I think ! @FranciBoudro can you please explain the expected result and visualize the problem if possible.

Comment: Okay i've got script to upload an image, a Title and a Text... And I want to echo into a Modal slider... Why my images not fit with texts... Random is fine but popup show both texts not separatly... Bests regards Boys

Comment: There is 2 images and 2 texts/Titles but unfortunatly each images popup the both texts in the window... Could I separate the texts/Titles to match on each images?

Comment: You can visualize [link](http://laboyer.com/laboyer.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second loop cannot iterate through the `mysqli_result` object. You need either to iterate again through results using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` or a better solution is to temporary store output of all modals in the array during while iteration and then after while loop, output it. Also, use integer variable to increment it during `while` loop and assign it as a suffix to modal id, that would differentiate modal for each record:

```
<?php

$modals = [];
$key = 1;
while ( $alaune = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $resultat6 ) ) {
    if ( ! empty( $alaune ) ) {
        echo '<div class="single_iteam"><img alt="" src="changements/une/images/' . $alaune["alaunePic"] . '" class="alaunePic">';
        echo '<div class="slider_article">';
        echo '<h2><a class="slider_tittle" href="#">' . $alaune["alauneTitre"] . '</a></h2>';
        echo '<p class="alaunetexte truncate">' . $alaune["alauneTexte"] . '</p>';

        ?>
        <a href="#" class="modal-trigger" data-modal="modal-name-<?php echo $key;  ?>">Lire la suite...</a>
        <?php echo '</div>';

        echo '</div>';


        $tempModal = '<div class="modal" id="modal-name-' . $key . '"><div class="modal-sandbox"></div><div class="modal-box"><div class="modal-header"><div class="close-modal">&#10006;</div>' .
                 '<h1>' . $alaune["alauneTitre"] . '</h1><p>' . $alaune["alauneTexte"] . '</p></div>' .
                 '<div class="modal-body"><br /><button class="close-modal"> Fermer </button></div></div></div>';


        $modals[]  = $tempModal;

        $key++;
    }
}

echo '</div>';

foreach($modals as $modal){

    echo $modal;
}



?>
```

Comment: Okay wow niklaz sincerely thousands of thanks but results is the same I've got my popup showing both results. Why cant I separate images and Text/Titles?

Comment: @FranciBoudro, I have edited my answer. Another issue was that you have been constructing one modal, with one ID and modal triggers referring to that same ID. Now I have split this into one trigger and one modal for each record.

Comment: Awesome... You are a genius. I dont know how You made it but it work. I spend a lot of time on this and finally ask some help. I thanks You so much. Best Regards.